# How to find all descendants from flat tree structure

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I have a flat data that represent the hierarchical relationship as below:

> ```
> ID    Name    PID
> 0     A       NULL
> 1     B       0
> 2     C       0
> 4     D       1
> 5     E       1
> 6     F       4
> 3     G       0
> ```

This table represents the 'data table', where PID indicates the parent element. 
For example, in the first row we see that A has PID null whereas B has PID 0, which means that B’s parent is A, because 0 is the ID of A, and A is the root element, because it does not have a PID. Similarly, C has parent A because C too has PID 0, and 0 is the ID of A.

I create a class `RecordHolder` to represent the above table. I also implement the method `processRecordHolder`

```
public Map<String, List<String>> processRecordHolder()
```

The returned map uses element as keys, and holds collections of descendant nodes as values. For example, the first item in the map corresponds to element A, which has many descendants, whereas element C has no descendant. The order of members in the output is not important.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

     RecordHolder dt = new RecordHolder();

     dt.addRow(0, "A", null);
     dt.addRow(1, "B", 0);
     dt.addRow(2, "C", 0);
     dt.addRow(4, "D", 1);
     dt.addRow(5, "E", 1);
     dt.addRow(6, "F", 4);
     dt.addRow(3, "G", 0);

     System.out.println("Output:");
     System.out.println(dt.processRecordHolder());
 }

Output:
{D=[F], A=[B, C, G, D, E, F], B=[D, E, F]}
or
{D=[F], E=null, F=null, G=null, A=[B, C, G, D, E, F], B=[D, E, F], C=null}
```

Below is my implementation of `Record` which I am able to come up so far:

```java
public class Record {

    public Integer id;
    public String name;
    public Integer parentId;
    public Record parent;
    public Collection<Record> children;

    public Record(Integer id, String name, Integer parentId) {
        this();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    public Record() {
       children = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<Record, Boolean>())
    }

    public Collection<Record> getChildren() {
       return children;
    }

    public Record getParent() {
       return parent;
    }

    public Integer getParentId() {
       return parentId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Record{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", parentId=" + parentId + '}';
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
       final int prime = 31;
       int result = 1;
       result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
       result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
       result = prime * result  + ((parentId == null) ? 0 : parentId.hashCode());
       return result;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof Record)) {
        return false;
    }
    Record other = (Record) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null) {
        return false;
        }
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null) {
        return false;
        }
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (parentId == null) {
        if (other.parentId != null) {
        return false;
        }
    } else if (!parentId.equals(other.parentId)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    }    
}
```

Now I am not able to understand other step what should I do?

Comment: This seems very complicated. My intuitive approach would've been to create an array using the ID as indexes and create linkedlist-like nodes as the values in the array. (Basically, use reference fields in each node to refer to children and an array to hold all nodes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
public class RecordHolder {

    Map<Integer,String> namesById = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer,List<Integer>> childrenById = new HashMap<>();

    public void addRow(Integer id, String name, Integer parent) {
        namesById.put(id, name);
        List<Integer> children = childrenById.get(parent);
        if (children == null) {
            children = new ArrayList<>();
            childrenById.put(parent, children);
        }
        children.add(id);
    }

    public Map<String,List<String>> processRecordHolder() {
        Map<String,List<String>> results = new HashMap<>();
        descendants(null, results);
        return results;
    }

    private List<String> descendants(Integer id, Map<String, List<String>> results) {
        final List<String> childrenNames = new ArrayList<>();

        final List<Integer> childrenIds = childrenById.get(id);
        if (childrenIds != null && childrenIds.size() > 0) {
            for (Integer childrenId : childrenIds) {

                final String childName = namesById.get(childrenId);
                childrenNames.add(childName);

                final List<String> grandchildrenNames = descendants(childrenId, results);
                childrenNames.addAll(grandchildrenNames);
            }

            if (id != null) {
                results.put(namesById.get(id), childrenNames);
            }
        }

        return childrenNames;
    }
}
```

Comment: David and david. That's just too funny.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you'd like to try my simpler idea for implementation, here it is in brief detail. This way, you can decide whether you want to use your current idea or try to start over using this idea. (note the code below is presented as a pseudo-Java outline, it won't compile and is not tested):

```
int numNodes = 7;
Node[] nodes = new Node[numNodes];
//Read in your file here using a Scanner/FileReader or something
int ID = 0;
char value = 0;
int PID = 0;
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    ID = scan.next();
    value = scan.next();
    PID = scan.next();
    nodes[ID] = new Node(value, PID);
}
```

And then a node class:

```
class Node{
    char value;
    Node parent;
    public Node(value, parentID){
        this.value = value;
        if(parentID == -1)
            parent = null;
        else
            parent = nodes[parentID]; //nodes will have to be a global array or get passed to the constructor
    }
}
```

Note that this constructor will only work if the item in nodes[parentID] has been initialized previously. (This is the case for your current input file order, but might not be in other situations.)

### Ancestry:

To find the ancestry of a node using ID with this approach simply do:

```
printAncestry(nodes[ID]);

void printAncestry(Node n){
    System.out.println("Child: " + n.value);
    System.out.println("Ancestry: ");
    while(n.parent != null){
        n = n.parent;
        System.out.println(n.value);
    }
}
```